# Get day of week by passing specific week and year javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get day of week by passing week and year ?

Ex: day of week 8th of year 2018 is 20th->27th . day of week 10th of year 2020 is 1st->7th

Comment: With the referenced Q&A you can get the start date of the given week. It is then easy to get the date parts from that.